# java null pointer error on inflating an xml for a custom listView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, inflate

I get a null pointer error on inflating my xml when creating a custom listView. I know it's probably something really simple and I'm just overlooking it, but I can't figure it out.

I get the error the first line after the if statement: convertView = inflater.inflate();

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Deck Deck = this.getItem(position);

        TextView title;
        Button study;
        Button edit;
        Button add;
        Button delete;
        //if theres no view yet created on the screen, create one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flash_card_row, null);

            //give the views their respective ID's
            title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.flash_card_title);
            study = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.flash_card_study);
            edit = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.flash_card_edit);
            add = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.flash_card_add_to_deck);
            delete = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.flash_card_delete_from_deck);

            convertView.setTag(new flashCardViewHolder(title, study, edit, add, delete));
        }
        //this gets called when the user scrolls down or up the screen and the adapter
        //wants to maximize efficiency by just calling the viewHolder instead of findViewById
        else {
            flashCardViewHolder viewHolder = (flashCardViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            title = viewHolder.getTitle();
            study = viewHolder.getStudy();
            edit = viewHolder.getEdit();
            add = viewHolder.getAdd();
            delete = viewHolder.getDelete();
        }

        //working on it, currently null
        //title.setText(Statics.listOfDecks.get(position).getTitle());

        //down here is where you set the values for all your views/objects
        //such as Buttons or textViews.
        study.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Here is the xml file I'm inflating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/flash_card_study"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/flash_card_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flash_card_study"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/flash_card_add_to_deck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flash_card_edit"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/flash_card_delete_from_deck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flash_card_add_to_deck"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flash_card_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/flash_card_delete_from_deck"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/flash_card_delete_from_deck"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

edit: logcat report

```
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at com.example.studyOptions.FlashCardListViewAdapter.getView(FlashCardListViewAdapter.java:115)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-17 21:25:18.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1584):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your log cat output with the exception. Everything looks ok but it's hard to tell without the error in front.

Comment: So, did you initialize `inflater`?